How to turn off indentation bar in VSCode
When I preview a markdown file in VS Code, there is always one line that has indentation bar at the beginning of that line. I am not sure how turn it off:

I did try to turn off indentation from settings but the bar still keeps showing. How can I hide the indicator?

Does it go away if you disable the setting Markdown > Preview: Mark Editor Selection?

Thank you so much. Disabling "Markdown > Preview: Mark Editor Selection" worked

You can control whether or not the selection indicator is visible in the markdown preview using the boolean VS Code setting markdown.preview.markEditorSelection. Set it to false to hide the indicator.
In settings.json:
{
  // Mark the current editor selection in the Markdown preview
  "markdown.preview.markEditorSelection": true,
}

Selection indicator visible (default)
{
  // Don't mark the current editor selection in the Markdown preview
  "markdown.preview.markEditorSelection": false,
}

Selection indicator hidden
